# check user id exists in database using ajax json C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i want to check whether a user name entered in a textbox exists in the database without a postback .And i'm using ajax jquery method the ide behind it is that when the user enters a name the method checks whether it exists in the database or not ,if it exists label will be shown such as "Username Exists" and otherwise the label  will be hidden.Now The problem is even if give a username exist in the database or otherwise page just keep on showing an alert message "error".Don't know what the problem is ??

ajax jquery method used

```
$("#txtteamname").focusout(function () {
           var txtFld = document.getElementById("txtteamname");

           if ( txtFld.value == 'Team Name') {

               this.style.color = '#787878';
           }
           else if (txtFld.value == ' ') {

               this.style.color = '#787878';
           }
           else {
               this.style.color = 'black';
               $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   url: 'teamcheck.asmx/teamnamecheck',
                   data: "{'team':'" + txtFld + "' }",
                   dataType: "json",
                   async: false,
                   success: function (msg) {
                       if (d.msg == 'exist') {
                           $("#Label8").show();
                       }
                   },
                   error: function () {

                      alert("Error");
                   }
               });

           }
```

C#

```
     [WebMethod]
    public static string teamnamecheck(string team)
    {

       string flag = "non";
        SqlDataReader dr;
    string str = "server=JITHU;uid=*****;pwd=***********;database=*********";
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
string rs= "select teamname from usertable where teamname ='" + team ; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("rs", con);

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if ((dr.Read()))
        {
            flag = "exist";
            return flag;
        }
        con.Close();
        return flag;

    }
}
```

Comment: open your debugging tools(press f12) and check if any error in your network tab, add a breakpoint in your code behind and see if it did hit the breakpoint, if in the debugging tools you see the red cross at the top right, click it and see what is the error message

Comment: Can you hit the `teamcheck.asmx/teamnamecheck` service in the browser manually?

Comment: method is being called or not??

Comment: @DeeMac when i hit the teamcheck.asmx/teamname check page manually it shows this "teamcheck

The following operations are supported. For a formal definition, please review the Service Description.

This web service is using http://tempuri.org/ as its default namespace.

Recommendation: Change the default namespace before the XML Web service is made public."

Comment: @user3001945 change your error to this `error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(XMLHttpRequest); alert(textStatus); alert(errorThrown); }`, what is the result of each error?

Comment: @Kyojimaru now it shows message box such as  [object OBJECT],error and internal server error

Comment: This is not related to the actual question but please read about `SQL Injection`, name your variables better, extract the connection string out of this method.

Answer (score -1):

I think your main problem is in this code

```
data: "{'team':'" + txtFld + "' }",
```

where you described txtFld like this

```
var txtFld = document.getElementById("txtteamname");
```

which will make txtFld as an `HTML DOM` and not a `string` like what you need in your server side here

```
public static string teamnamecheck(string team)
```

so your AJAX call didn't reach the function in your server, try changing your data to this

```
data: "{'team':'" + txtFld.value + "' }",
```

and just to make sure it hits the server, place a breakpoint in your server code anywhere inside the

```
public static string teamnamecheck(string team) {
    ... // your code, place the breakpoint here
}
```

and uncomment this line in the `teamcheck.asmx`

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Comment: i have made the changes you suggested but still no luck and also placed a breakpoint but the function call didn't the hit the server

Comment: @Jijith what is the results of `txtFld.value`? and try changing `public static string teamnamecheck(string team)` to `public string teamnamecheck(string team)` and have you uncomment this line `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]` in the `teamcheck.asmx`